# Demonstrate threshold h2o kmeans

Tags: r, k-means, h2o, threshold

I am using h2o kmeans in R to divide my population. The method need to be audited, so I would like to explain the threshold used in the h2o's kmeans.

In the documentation of h2o kmeans (http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/k-means.html), it is said :

> H2O uses proportional reduction in error (PRE) to determine when to
>   stop splitting.  The PRE value is calculated based on the sum of
>   squares within (SSW).
>
> PRE=(SSW[before split]−SSW[after split])/SSW[before split]
>
> H2O stops splitting when PRE falls below a threshold, which is a
>   function of the number of variables and the number of cases as
>   described below:
>
> threshold takes the smaller of these two values:
>
> either 0.8 or [0.02 + 10/number_of_training_rows +
>   2.5/(number_of_model_features)^2]

The source code (https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-algos/src/main/java/hex/kmeans/KMeans.java) is given as :

> final double rel_improvement_cutoff = Math.min(0.02 + 10. /
>   _train.numRows() + 2.5 / Math.pow(model._output.nfeatures(), 2), 0.8);

**Where does this threshold come from ? Are there scientific papers about it ?**

Comment: Including links for that specific documentation and sources will not hurt, but add a better understanding of the context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am responsible for that threshold. I developed it by running numerous datasets -- artificial and real -- through the k-means algorithm. I began some years ago working with SSW improvement and testing it as a chi-square variable, as recommended by John Hartigan. This criterion failed in a number of instances, so I switched to PRE. The equation above is the result of fitting a nonlinear model to results on datasets with a known number of clusters. When I wrote the k-means program for Tableau, I used this same PRE criterion. After I left Tableau for H2O, they substituted the Calinski-Harabasz index for my PRE rule, producing similar results. 
Leland Wilkinson, Chief Scientist, H2O.